# Kotlin API - endpoint for users

Tags: api, spring, kotlin

I am writing API in Kotlin - this is my first code in this language. I implemented a very primitive 'player' endpoint. I was wondering if I am doing everything ok (please don't mind the static variables - I will put them in the database later)

```
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import pl.domain.Player
import pl.rest.dto.PlayerDto

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/player")
class PlayerController {

    var players: Map<Long, Player> = mapOf(
            1L to Player(1L, "user1", "password1"),
            2L to Player(2L, "user2", "password2"),
            3L to Player(3L, "user3", "password3")
    )

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    fun fetchPlayer(@PathVariable id : Long): ResponseEntity<Player> =
        players[id]?.let { ResponseEntity.ok(it) } ?: ResponseEntity.notFound().build()

    @PostMapping
    fun createPlayer(@RequestParam username: String, @RequestParam password : String): ResponseEntity<Player> {
        val playerId = (players.size + 1).toLong()
        val player = Player(playerId, username, password)
        players = players.plus(player.id to player)
        return ResponseEntity.ok(player)
    }

    @PutMapping
    fun updatePlayer(@RequestBody playerDto: PlayerDto): ResponseEntity<Player> {
        return players[playerDto.id]
                ?.apply {
                    username = playerDto.username ?: username
                    password = playerDto.password ?: password
                }?.let { ResponseEntity.ok(it) } ?: ResponseEntity.badRequest().build()
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    fun deletePlayer(@PathVariable id: Long): ResponseEntity<Nothing> {
        players = players.minus(id)
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build()
    }

}
```

`PlayerDto.kt`:

```
class PlayerDto(var id: Long? = null, var username: String? = null, var password: String? = null)
```

`Player.kt`:

```
data class Player(var id: Long, var username: String, var password: String)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've two recommendations that probably have more to do with design rather than with code. The first one is to change the API path to `players`:

```
@RequestMapping("/players")
```

I personally like to pluralize resource path names even if [it's widely discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845772/rest-uri-convention-singular-or-plural-name-of-resource-while-creating-it).

The other one is to modify your *PUT* endpoint in order to also accept resources to be created. That way you would have a single endpoint which accepts a list of players, where players might be new or already have an id. For the first case, the system must create them, for the second, update them. That's also a [mather of disussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest) in the net.